# Trouble creating symlinked folder

Tags: command-line, symlink, smartcontracts, truffle

I am following the DrizzlexReact tutorial @ https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-react

I've reached a point where I have to symlink my contract folder using the command: 'mklink \D contracts ....\build\contracts'.
When typed as is from the tutorial I get a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error.
I've even tried quotes around the file names/paths. Nothing.

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a '/D, as per mklink docs & not '\D', as per the tutorial.